# How to enforce delete the Enterprise Search Service Application in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I tried to delete the Enterprise Search Service Application and then install it again.

But there is no way to delete the service application.

1. Enter to central administration
2. Enter to manage service applications
3. Delete Enterprise Search Service Application

We got an error : object refference not set to an instance.

I also tried to delete it via powershell command, and got the same error.

How can i reinstall this service application ?

thanks for answering.